# How to prevent XSS attacks on my web app jQuery and Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, xss

I have a web app which is primarily running on jQuery, Twitter Bootstrap and HTML5. The app has a few text boxes and text areas which just have required field validations for now. I am told that the site is VERY vulnerable to XSS attacks and I don't know much about the subject. I was also told that I may be able to use something like an ngsanitize in the Angular world to fix some of the XSS issues that I might face.

In jQuery/Bootstrap, are there any XSS libraries that I can use to make my life easy in this regard?

Updating code:

I just have some form elements like this and it's followed by a Submit button.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="test">This is some text <span style="color:red">*</span></label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="test" required></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="comment">Comments </label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="comment"></textarea>
</div>
```

---

Update:

So it sounds like the data that's saved from this page would be fetched by another user in a different session and I should take care of the fact that the user is unable to enter a script inside the textarea. I am not doing any encoding/decoding at this point and can really use some pointers as to how I can only permit letters, numbers and punctuation in my fields. Can I use a filtering/validation library to whitelist some input values/characters. Also, what sort of encoding should I be using and any pointers to that would help.

Comment: We can't possibly tell you where your security vulnerability is without you showing us your code. In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have added some code. My code is really just a form with some form fields and a Submit button. Really basic form in Bootstrap. Any other code I should add?

Comment: The code above has nothing to do with how XSS works, and there is nothing wrong with it. I suggest you [**read up**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) about XSS, and then include the relevant code here once you have worked out what that is.

Comment: Unless you show us the back-end code that handles the submit of the form, there's nothing we can help you with for XSS. As this has nothing to do with it.

Comment: with advancement, the browsers themselves prevent the XSS attacks now.

Comment: Added some more detail. The backend code is a simple REST controller which does REST calls, some GETs and some POSTS. Nothing fancy. We use an SSO solution for authentication so i'm not implementing any token based authentication like JWT, just using whats provided by SSO.